# Send Table Row Data via AJAX Based on Checkbox Checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a table with multiple columns (index.php). One column is a checkbox. Whenever the checkbox is checked, it displays another column where you can select a quantity.

I want to then be able to hit a button called "Add to Order" and have it use AJAX to add any selected rows to the index-order.php page. After all selections have been made, I want to be able to click the "Checkout" button and have it take me to the index-order.php page where it should display all of the added selections in a table.

I know how to navigate to the index-order.php page so my main question is how can I add the selected rows to the page while using ajax and staying on the current page when doing so?

Index.php code:

```
<form name="form1" action="index-order.php"> 

<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button type="submit" id="checkout" name="order">Checkout</button>
</section>
</form>

<form name="form2" method="POST" action="index-order.php"> 

<section id="addToOrder">   
<button type="submit" class="order" id="order" name="order" value="AddToOrder">Add to Order</button>
</section>

<br>


<div id="my-div2" class="ui-widget">
<div class="ui-widget">

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
        <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check"></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][loc]" class="loc ui-widget-content" id="loc-<?php echo intval ($row['Loc'])?>"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]" class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][sku]" class="sku ui-widget-content" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][special-id]" class="special-id ui-widget-content" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][description]" class="description ui-widget-content" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][quantity]" class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][unit]" class="unit ui-widget-content" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" name="value" id="test"></td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>

</form>
```

Index-order.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['rows'])): ?>
<table cellspacing="20">
    <tr align="center">
        <th>Loc</th>
        <th>Report Code</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Special ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Quantity #</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach($_POST['rows'][0] as $row): 
    ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><?php echo $row['loc']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rp-code']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sku']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['special-id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quant']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        endforeach; 
    ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

JavaScript (obviously needs some work. Posting what I have so far):

```
$(function () {

  $('#form2').on('submit', function (e) {

  if($('input.check').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('tr');

      e.preventDefault();

      var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index-order.php',
        data: $('#form2').serialize(),
        success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
      });

}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get all the siblings of the current checked checkbox and based on that get all the columns and separate the data to finally send it via ajax.

You can do something like this:

```
$('#form2').on('submit', function (e) {
    $checkbox = $(this).find('input.check:checked').parent('td'); //Finds the checked checkbox's column inside #form2
    $otherColumns = $checkbox.nextAll(); //Gets all the siblings
});
```

The above code will get you all the other columns next to the checked checkbox inside your form. What you an do next is travel across `$otherColumns` and get each individual value using `$otherColums.eq(n).html()` where n is the number of the column you are trying to get.